# How do I sum up all the values related to the specific id in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have columns in a dataframe like this :

```
id        value
 a           2 
 a           1  
 b           8
 a           0  
 a           2
```

I have thousands of ids like these. I want to sum all the values with the same id so that I get a dataframe like :

```
a   5
b   8
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby('id').sum()`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.groupby`

```
df.groupby('id').sum()
```